# Revisiting MS Access as Enterprise Software

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

It's been 10 years since this question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469436/ms-access-as-enterprise-software/470093#comment95197039_470093) and I'd like to see what current thoughts are.

We have a third party app that we've supported for at least that long. It's an Access runtime application that connects to SQL Server and contains *highly* confidential data.

Some years ago we moved the database to an SQL Server running on Server Core. More recently we've been asked to run the first upgrade of the database schema in 6 years. The vendor provided upgrade package appears to be built using VB6 and won't run on the server. It also doesn't support running the updates remotely. We have a couple of ways that we can get it done but it has presented me with an opportunity to finally move on from what *I* think is not an enterprise product.

As part of that I've been asked *why* I think this product is so bad and, in my estimation, antiquated. My immediate internal response is that it's not a real application, it's Access. That's compounded by the fact that we're paying a pretty good bit for it and I think that there are better, more robust solutions now available that are also cheaper (I think in the end that's all that *should* matter).

That said I acknowledge that there my be some bias in my opinions on this particular app. Looking back at that old post a few things stand out.

- I think there's a big difference between internally developed applications built this way and paid for solutions. Supporting an internally developed app written in Access may still have some positives. I don't think the positives pointed out in the top answer hold up when you're paying someone for it. The disadvantages are precisely what we're running in to.
- Reporting isn't being done in Access. It's now mostly being done with outside tools. Most users want to see web based reporting.
- A couple of the responses mentioned *professional Access developers* or this type of application being *the COBOL of the 21st century*. I think that's an apt description. I'm not sure professional Access developers still exist. How long should we try to maintain this and how long do we think the vendor will be able to?

> I think the main mistake about Access is to consider it as a tool made for amateurs to develop applications. It can work this way, but keep in mind that amateur development will give you amateur applications, while professional development will give you professional results

Maybe this is the crux of my problem in particular. I'm not convinced that **our** application is 'professional'. It *feels* semi-pro if I'm generous. The VB6 updater is one clue and there are other components that have given me cause for concern over the years.

Fair or not, in my mind, most, if not all Access applications in the enterprise have these same issues. At the end of the day, the question is whether it serves the needs of the department using it.

Where does Access fit in the enterprise in 2019?

Comment: This topic, while interesting, is off topic here because it is 100% opinion based. In my opinion Access belongs in the trash bin.

Comment: @SeanLange I bet you said the same about my first true love... Visual FoxPro

Comment: @JohnCappelletti LOL that is the first language my wife worked with in the real world. Pretty sure she would tell you where that one belongs. ;)

Comment: Do I like Access? No. Are there better tools for the job? Depending on expectations that answer could vary. Have I enjoyed tons of well paid contracts that require me to use Access/SQLServer/Oracle combos to get the job done? Yes. Is there still a need for this in various environments? Absolutely. Despite my opinions, it still has a place in the business world. One of the clients I have a contract with right now enjoys access b/c of the ease of use in terms of query building. Regardless of whether or not they use it kind of like an amped up excel. I have often tutored SQL noobs using Access

Comment: @SeanLange I looked across the StackExchange sites to see if there was a better place because, as you say, it is largely opinion. I considered ServerFault but I chose here because of the question from 10 years ago.

Comment: Well it probably should have been closed 10 years ago as being opinion based. I don't think anywhere on StackExchange is really well suited. It tends to start arguments and all sorts of bad things. There is no right or wrong answer here. It really boils down to what works for your company and the technology you are using. If it works for you then spectacular. To be fair, 10 years ago I would probably not have been as nice about Access as I am today.

Comment: This question is indeed very much opinion-based, so I won't answer, just a short opinion: Is Access suited for data storage in the enterprise environment? Clearly not. Is Access suited as a polished front-end for a database without allowing the users to use advanced features like VBA themselves? Also no imo. The main features of Access that can't be replaced are the features for power users, such as writing your own queries, linking Excel files and local tables with your enterprise database, and more. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] I support applications that come with a core set of functionality, the ability to update and restore this core functionality, and allows users to directly access tables and create their own workflow themselves. This is for an environment where most users are scientists with moderate computer skills, and often have highly specific needs of the database. A similar solution, offering the same ease of use and features, really can't be created in any other environment.

Comment: But do ANY of these issues apply to any other platform? It really comes down to in-house development vs that of buying off the self. And not sure what you mean by “cost”. The access runtime been free for many years now. I mean, tons of applications such as VB6 still exist, yet they use ADO, and that’s been depreciated. (.net uses ado.net – a VERY different beast). I mean, what other software systems are you using that comes from a vendor, and what been the experience? Everything else always seems better until you actually start using it. As noted, this is off topic for stack overflow.