# how to attach a setup file to a setup project for a C# application in visual studio

Tags: c#, ms-access, installation

I am developing an application in which it deals with reading data from excel files (xls and xlsx).

Therefore, it requires that Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 has to be installed on the clients' PC. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

I dont know whether when I create a setup project for the C# application, the setup process will check whether the client has install that Engine above or not. If not then it will install it before setting up the applicaiton.

My question is that: how to to it with creating a setup project for a C# application in visual studio 2010?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to do this on VS 2010
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Win_App_Setup_Project.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access 2007 Engine: How do I include it in my .msi installer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378264/access-2007-engine-how-do-i-include-it-in-my-msi-installer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would you try like this you can add your microsoft access databse engine

Like the **file attribute** in the [appSettings Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx) or the [SectionInformation.ConfigSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx)?

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="machine-specific.config">
        <add key="Application Name" value="MyApplication" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```